# How can I add one of two random numbers to each row of a csv proportionately?

Tags: bash, csv, random, awk, sed

I have a csv that contains 100 rows by three columns of random numbers:

```
100, 20, 30
746, 82, 928
387, 12, 287.3
12, 47, 2938
125, 198, 263
...
12, 2736, 14
```

In bash, I need to add another column that will be either a 0 or a 1. However, (and here is the hard part), I need to have 20% of the rows with 0s, and 80% with 1s.
Result:

```
100, 20, 30, 0
746, 82, 928, 1
387, 12, 287.3, 1
12, 47, 2938, 1
125, 198, 263, 0
...
12, 2736, 14, 1
```

What I have tried:

```
sed '1~3s/$/0/' mycsv.csv
```

but i thought I could replace the 1~3 with 'random number' but that doesn't work.
Maybe a loop would? Maybe sed or awk?

Answer (score 5):

Using awk and `rand()` to get randomly 0s and 1s with 20 % probability of getting a 0:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=", ";srand()}{print $0,(rand()>0.2)}' file
```

Output:

```
100, 20, 30, 1
746, 82, 928, 1
387, 12, 287.3, 1
12, 47, 2938, 0
125, 198, 263, 1
..., 0
12, 2736, 14, 1
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS=", "                 # set output field separator
    srand()                  # time based seed for rand()
}
{
    print $0,(rand()>0.2)    # output 0/1 ~ 20/80
}' file
```

As `srand()` per se is time (seconds) based, depending on the need, you might want to introduce external seed for it, for example, from Bash:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)}...'
```

**Update**: A version that first counts the lines in the file, calculates how many are 20 % 0s and randomly picks a 0 or a 1 and keeps count:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM '
BEGIN {
    srand(seed)                               # feed the seed to random
}
NR==1 {                                       # processing the first record
    while((getline line < FILENAME)>0)        # count the lines in the file
        nr++                                  # nr stores the count
    for(i=1;i<=nr;i++)                        # produce 
        a[(i>0.2*nr)]++                       # 20 % 0s, 80 % 1s
}
{
    p=a[0]/(a[0]+a[1])                        # probability to pick 0 or 1
    print $0 ". " (a[v=(rand()>p)]?v:v=(!v))  # print record and 0 or 1
    a[v]--                                    # remove 0 or 1
}' file
```

Comment: Be aware that the usage of a random seed is never good practice as it creates results that are not reproducible.  Furthermore, this method makes it possible that you will end up with all ones or all zeros.

Comment: @James Brown: The OP wants to have 20% zeroes, not approximately 20% zeroes. Your solution might (in, admittedly, rare cases) append a `1` to **all** the lines.

Comment: Updated with a version that keeps count of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is the following:

1. Create a sequence of 0 and 1's with the correct ratio:

   ```
   $ awk 'END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) print (i <= 0.8*FNR) }' file
   ```
2. Shuffle the output to randomize it:

   ```
   $ awk 'END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) print (i <= 0.8*FNR) }' file | shuf
   ```
3. Paste it next to the file with a <comma>-character as delimiter:

   ```
   $ paste -d, file <(awk 'END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) print (i <= 0.8*FNR) }' file | shuf)
   ```

The reason I do not want to use any form of random number generator, is that this could lead to 100% ones or 100% zeros. Or anything of that nature. The above produces the closest possible 80% of ones and 20% of zeros.

Another method would be a double parse with awk in the following way:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR) { next }
       (FNR==1) { for(i=1;i<NR;i++) a[i] = (i<0.8*(NR-1)) }
       { for(i in a) { print $0","a[i]; delete a[i]; break } }' file file
```

The above makes use of of the fact that `for(i in a)` cycles through the array in an undetermined way. You can see this by quickly doing

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","; for(i=1;i<=20;++i) a[i]; for(i in a) print i; printf "\n"}'
17,4,18,5,19,6,7,8,9,10,20,11,12,13,14,1,15,2,16,3,
```

But this is implementation dependent.

Finally, you could actually use `shuf` in awk to get to the desired result

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR) { next }
       (FNR==1) { cmd = "shuf -i 1-"(NR-1)" }
       { cmd | getline i; print $0","(i <= 0.8*(NR-FNR)) }' file file
```

Comment: Fantastic! The logic makes sense. Thank you for simplifying it!

Comment: @tbs35 If you like this solution, have a look at [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more a problem of algorithm than of programming. You state in your question: *I need to have 20% of the rows with 0s, and 80% with 1s.*. So the first question is, what to do, if the number of rows is not a multiple of 5. If you have 112 rows in total, 20% would be 22.4 rows, and this does not make sense.

Assuming that you can redefine your task to deal with that case, the simplest solution would be assign a 0 to the first 20% of the rows and a 1 to the remaining ones.

But say that you want to have some randomness in the distribution of the 0 and 1. One quick-and-dirty solution would be to create an array consisting of the numbers of zeroes and ones you are going to redeem in total, and in each iteration take a random element from this array (and remove it from the array).

Comment: The proportion I needed is slightly different. I know the number of lines. I used 20 and 80 for simplicity :)

Comment: That's fine. Then just use one of the methods I suggested. Or use a programming language which comes with possibilities to create random permutations. Matias Barrios suggested Python3, and it can be done similarily with Ruby for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous reply, Here is a Python 3 way to do this :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
import math
import random

totalOflines = len(open('columns.csv').readlines())
newColumn = ( [0] * math.ceil(totalOflines * 0.20) ) + ( [1] * math.ceil(totalOflines * 0.80) )
random.shuffle(newColumn)

csvr = csv.reader(open('columns.csv'), delimiter = ",")

i=0
for row in csvr:
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(row[0],row[1],row[2],newColumn[i]))
    i+=1
```

Regards!